# Not have all ARM template functions in Visual Studio

Tags: json, azure, azure-resource-manager

I would like to develop an arm template. as I am reading in [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions), there are some useful functions, which I can use.

My question is now, why I can not see some of these functions in visual studio for example [newGuid()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions)
or [guid()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions)
what should I do to have them in visual Studio?
I am using visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The visual studio don't have a IntelliSense for the ARM template, to do that you need to use visual studio code and use this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msazurermtools.azurerm-vscode-tools

With this, you will have IntelliSense for the ARM and you will see the functions and a lot of things. It greatly improves the creation and work with the Arm template!

Comment: i think it actually has?

Comment: Do you have a link for it?

Comment: mmmm I see, I never used it, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/create-visual-studio-deployment-project